# System.Diagnostics.Trace in referenced Class Library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, system.diagnostics

I have a `Asp.Net` (Web Api) project. In this project I reference another Class Library project.

The traces that are written in the referenced Class Library don't show up in my Log.

How can I make the traces off both projects show up in the same Log using `System.Diagnostics`? In other words, how can I make the referenced Class Library use the `web.config` Diagnostics settings from the Api Project? And if this isn't possible, how can I get the Traces that are written in the referenced Class Library in a Log at all?

I tried to add the `System.Diagnostics` settings from the `web.config` to a `app.config` but this doesn't seem to do anything at all.

**Api project:**

```
TraceSource source = new TraceSource("MyProject");
source.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 1, "My logged Trace");
```

**Referenced class library:**

```
TraceSource source = new TraceSource("MyProject");
source.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 1, "My disappearing Trace");
```

**Web.config**

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="MyProject" switchValue="All">
      <listeners>
        <clear />
        <add name="log" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="log"
         type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
         initializeData="Log.svclog"
    />
  </sharedListeners>
  <trace autoflush="true"/>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: can you also show you trace listeners configuration in configs ?

Comment: Yes I did, it's a simplified version off my listeners configuration.

Comment: Interesting, I reproduced your setup and have both your traces getting into file.

Comment: Could you in some way share your reproduced setup?

Comment: yeah give me a minute

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ojosdegris/5197153

Comment: It also works for me if I put this inside a Console Application. This gets me even more puzzled about why it doesn't work in my Api project. I'm gonna go through my Api again and otherwise make a new Api project and test that out. (Thanks a lot for your help and time)

Comment: yeap let me try with web.api project.

Comment: It actually also works with my mvc4 web.api project too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26474/discussion-between-jos-vinke-and-vittore)

Comment: Well, and have you figured it out? I seem to have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure trace listeners according to your class library configuration of tracesources. Do you own the code ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228993.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228984.aspx

Comment: Yes I do own both projects, I did configure trace listeners, but only the traces from the Api Project are logged.